# Displaying entity level error messages in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have written a custom annotation and placed the annotation on the entity level.

```
@ValidConfirmPassword
 public class User {...}
```

The custom validator is returning the invalid message, but, I am not able to display the message on the UI.

How should I display the error messsage specific to the entity using Thymeleaf?

Comment: Did you find a solution?